# Qual a anotação em Spring preciso usar com messageArrived do MQTTCallBack

Tags: java, spring, annotation, mqtt

Sou novato com Spring e estou tentando inserir no meu banco MySQL a partir da mensagem recebida do MQTT.
Eu criei minha aplicação da seguinte maneira:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MqttServiceApplication.class, args);
        context.registerShutdownHook();

        ProductionSubscribe();
    }

  public static void ProductionSubscribe() {
        try {
            IMqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.0.201:1883", new Date().getTime() + "");
            client.connect();

            ProductionCallBack productionCallBack = new ProductionCallBack();
            client.setCallback(productionCallBack);

            client.subscribe("/InputCounter/#");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Então implementei o MqttCallback

```
@Component
public class ProductionCallBack implements MqttCallback {

    @Autowired
    private MachineService machineService;

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        String name = s.replace("/InputCounter/", "").split("/")[0];
        Date now = new Date();

        EasyIOModel easyIOModel = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mqttMessage.toString(), EasyIOModel.class);

        // Get Machine
        Machine machine = machineService.getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(easyIOName);
        if (machine == null) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("deliveryComplete");
    }
}
```

Tudo está indo bem até a chamada do messageArrived, porém, quando vou usar o serviço machineService, ele está null. E não consigo acessar seus métodos

Se utilizo REST controllers, meus serviços funcionam bem... Mas eu não sei como fazer, ou quais anotações usar, no caso do MQTT, para poder chamar os meus serviços.

**edit**

SERVICE INTERFACE:

```
public interface MachineService {
    Machine getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(String machineName);
}
```

SERVICE:

```
@Service
public class MachineServiceImpl implements MachineService {

    @Inject
    private MachineRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Machine getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(String machineName) {
        return repository.getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(machineName);
    }
}
```

REPOSITORY:

```
@Repository
public interface MachineRepository extends JpaRepository<Machine, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM machine WHERE name = :machineName LIMIT 1")
    Machine getMachineByNameAndInputNumber(String machineName);
}
```

Obrigado,

Comment: Onde você está definindo o machineService ? Faltou declarar ele nesse componente private MachineService machineService para você conseguir usar, lembrando que o MachineService deve estar sendo gerenciado pelo spring, a classe deve ter anotada com o @service

Comment: Olá rnd, tudo bem? Na verdade eu não declarei, pois o que queria era algo semelhante a quando utilizo REST, e com o RequestMapping acaba não tendo necessidade de declarar. E sim, MachineService está com a anotação @Service.

Comment: Quando faço o que disse, de declarar dentro do meu método, funciona... O problema é que dentro do service, o meu @Repository também fica null. E acabo tendo o mesmo problema lá. Só que neste caso não posso simplesmente declarar. Uma vez que o repository na verdade é uma interface que extende JPA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663131/10534900 Exemplo do que quero dizer...

Comment: Poste o seu service e repository para ajudar na análise

Comment: Pronto, editei a postagem com eles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisar injetar o serviço na classe:

```
@Component
public class ProductionCallBack implements MqttCallback {

   @Autowired
   private MachineService machineService;

}
```

E o repository no serviço:

```
@Service
public class MachineServiceImpl implements MachineService {

    @Autowired
    private MachineRepository repository;

}
```

**Edit**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqttServiceApplication implements AsyncConfigurer, CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ProductionCallBack productionCallBack;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MqttServiceApplication.class, args);
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            IMqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.0.201:1883", new Date().getTime() + "");
            client.connect();


            client.setCallback(productionCallBack);

            client.subscribe("/InputCounter/#");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: brendonmiranda, erro meu, desculpe... Coloquei a parte do código errada. Eu já fiz isso e acabei de corrigir na pergunta. Ele está como comentou e ainda assim recebo null

Comment: você está injetando o repository com @ Autowired?

Comment: Fiz testes com @ Autowired e @Inject e ambos tem o mesmo problema. Mas nem chego a conseguir entrar no service para chamar o repository... Pois o Service vem null

Comment: A interface está anotada com @ component ? Posta o erro aqui tbm

Comment: Nenhuma delas está anotada como @component... Qual deveria? A MachineService?

Comment: Isso, anote a interface MachineService com @ component e poste o erro aqui também caso persista.

Comment: Acabei de colocar o @Component no MachineService e o mesmo erro persiste. Desse jeito eu tenho @ Component na interface MachineService e @ Service no MachineServiceImpl

Comment: Você consegue postar a classe completa que comporta seu método main ?

Comment: segue um print da classe > http://prntscr.com/r0cowz

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104276/discussion-between-brendonmiranda-and-fernando-muniz-erthal).